# Heroku using PostgreSQL is failing on initial push to build application, what's the deal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, deployment

I'll be as detailed as possible, but this issue is quite odd.

I've been working with Ruby on Rails 2.1.0 and Heroku, pushing out changes to a commercial application and I was instructed to create a test environment rather than work with the public environment (understandable. I figured everything would be solid, all I'd have to do is create a new app, push the source, and be back in action - it wasn't that simple. It's been almost 2 days of rebuilding my VM and verifying RVM versions to no avail.

Here's the error:

```
Total 1093 (delta 259), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote:  !
remote:  !     An error occurred while installing Ruby ruby-2.1.0
remote:  !     For supported Ruby versions see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles   /ruby-support#supported-runtimes
remote:  !     Note: Only the most recent version of Ruby 2.1 is supported on Cedar-14
remote:  !     Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl --fail --retry 3 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/cedar-14/ruby-2.1.0.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed unexpectedly:
remote:  !     
remote:  !     gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
remote:  !     tar: Child returned status 1
remote:  !     tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

Now here's the interesting part, nothing has changed, I made sure not to screw with the gem file, or any other issues (the Gemfile says ruby '2.1.0', just fyi), and I connect to the other application on the public environment versus my testing environment, and BAM. It works.

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.1.0
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using 1.6.3
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Using i18n 0.6.9
remote:        Using multi_json 1.8.4
remote:        Using minitest 4.7.5
remote:        Using atomic 1.1.14
remote:        Using builder 3.1.4
remote:        Using tzinfo 0.3.38
remote:        Using erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Using rack 1.5.2
remote:        Using polyglot 0.3.4
remote:        Using mime-types 1.25.1
remote:        Using activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.3
remote:        Using arel 4.0.2
remote:        Using american_date 1.1.0
remote:        Using rake 10.1.1
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.7.0
remote:        Using bcrypt-ruby 3.1.2
remote:        Using thor 0.18.1
remote:        Using execjs 2.0.2
remote:        Using hike 1.2.3
remote:        Using libv8 3.16.14.3
remote:        Using json 1.8.1
remote:        Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Using mini_portile 0.6.0
remote:        Using bundler 1.6.3
remote:        Using pg 0.17.1
remote:        Using tilt 1.4.1
remote:        Using remotipart 1.2.1
remote:        Using sass 3.2.14
remote:        Using ref 1.0.5
remote:        Using rack-test 0.6.2
remote:        Using warden 1.2.3
remote:        Using treetop 1.4.15
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.2.0
remote:        Using rdoc 4.1.1
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.1.3
remote:        Using uglifier 2.4.0
remote:        Using sprockets 2.10.1
remote:        Using therubyracer 0.12.1
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.6.2.1
remote:        Using mail 2.5.4
remote:        Using sdoc 0.4.0
remote:        Using activesupport 4.0.2
remote:        Using actionpack 4.0.2
remote:        Using jbuilder 1.5.3
remote:        Using climate_control 0.0.3
remote:        Using railties 4.0.2
remote:        Using activemodel 4.0.2
remote:        Using actionmailer 4.0.2
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 2.0.1
remote:        Using cocaine 0.5.3
remote:        Using activerecord 4.0.2
remote:        Using paperclip 3.5.4
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
remote:        Using devise 3.2.2
remote:        Using jquery-rails 3.1.0
remote:        Using sass-rails 4.0.1
remote:        Using turbolinks 2.2.1
remote:        Using rails 4.0.2
remote:        Using twitter-bootstrap-rails 2.2.8
remote:        Your bundle is complete!
```

My question is, how can this be occuring? Nothing on my system has changed, and I'm unsure of what to change in order for it to deploy to the test environment properly. Any tips/tricks/advice will be appreciate, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error w.r.t. heroku supported ruby versions seems to be raised only when creating a new application; not when pushing to an existing application.

If you change the ruby version on the test environment to `ruby 2.1.5`, it would work perfectly.

On the topic of setting up a test environment for a heroku app, check out https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments ; it talks about how to set up a staging environment linked to the production application with the same code base.

Answer (score 0):

> An error occurred while installing Ruby ruby-2.1.0
>
> For supported Ruby versions see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
>
> **Note: Only the most recent version of Ruby 2.1 is supported on Cedar-14**

On [that page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes):

```
MRI:
* 1.8.7 : patchlevel 376, Rubygems : 1.8.24 (Not supported on cedar-14)
* 1.9.2 : patchlevel 327, Rubygems: 1.3.7.1 (Not supported on cedar-14)
* 1.9.3 : patchlevel 551, Rubygems : 1.8.23.2
* 2.0.0 : patchlevel 598, Rubygems : 2.0.14
* 2.1.5 : patchlevel 265, Rubygems: : 2.2.2
* 2.2.0 : patchlevel 0, Rubygems: ; 2.4.5
```

No Ruby 2.1.0.  As far as I know you've always got the latest patchlevel of the Ruby you specified, but Ruby changed how it versions itself in 2.1 onwards.  Instead of having 1.9.3p598 and p600 and p700 etc, you will have Ruby 2.1.1, 2.1.2, etc.  So now, since you put so specific a version in your Gemfile, it rejects it because it is outdated.

It should be as simple as updating your Gemfile to have `ruby '2.1.5'`.